# What is the relationship between a SPID and a Connection in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, connection-pooling, spid

Can a SPID be used by two connections, while both connections are open?

If a connection is returned to a connection pool, will it hold on to the SPID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can a SPID be used by two connections,
>   while both connections are open?

No, each open connection will have its own SPID.

> If a connection is returned to a
>   connection pool, will it hold on to
>   the SPID?

Yes, as long as the connection is open, it will be associated with one SPID.

You can test this yourself by querying `sys.sysprocesses`.  Rebooting a client machine should clear its connection pool.