# What is the relation between Sybase spid and SQL query

Tags: sap-ase

As I understand from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742693/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-spid-and-a-connection-in-sql-server) my Sybase ASE database connection has its own SPID. My question is: are complex queries with nested subselects executed by that single SPID? Or does Sybase spawn other SPID's to execute complex queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If parallel processing is enabled, it is possible for `spids` to spawn other processes.  This could occur in large complex queries if the optimizer chooses parallel execution, reorgs and other similar database actions.

If this occurs, then the newly spawned `spid` will have the parent `spid` in the `fid` (Family ID) column of `master..sysprocesses`, or in the out put of `sp_who`

More information on [Parallel Queries can be found in the documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/CHDGHJBC.htm).